# How can I have multiple conditions on conflict with Postgres?

Tags: postgresql

I have a table with different columns and I am doing an `insert` (as `upsert`) which should update values only in case of conflict:

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, address, postcode, email)
VALUES ( .... ) 
ON CONFLICT (name, address) 
DO
    UPDATE
    SET email = EXCLUDED.email || ';' || customers.email;
```

but also I need an extra condition liek `ON CONFLICT (address, postcode)`.

in a sort of:

```
INSERT INTO clients (name, address, postcode, email)
VALUES ( .... ) 
ON CONFLICT (name, address) OR CONFLICT (address, postcode) -- this is the change I am referring to
DO
    UPDATE
    SET email = EXCLUDED.email || ';' || customers.email;
```

How can I achieve that as only one conflict can be managed?